# Key Pad driven web UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

I have a fancy web page with lots on JQuery included.
Currently i am struggling to find a solution to make it keypad driven.
I want the buttons on the page to be clicked when the user press some key combination
(e.q. save should happen if the user click on Ctl+S button on the keypad.
Does anyone have experience doing something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [access keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_key).

Comment: This did work on the website.
The wiki page did say about some issues with  accesskey on adaptive technology and screen reading technology.
What is your say on this?
Is it a good idea to still use it, will the use of accesskey pass the accessibility test we have?

Comment: One option is to provide an option to disable accesskeys if a user desires it - for instance, GMail does this with a setting in the Account Options area.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about detecting keypress events there is too solutions that I have been working with. First of all you can use an input tag to detect keys, and secondly you can use an on screen keyboard for those people that don't have any keypress detection.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/33888661@N07/3880797326/

Its a pretty sad state though either way, unfortunately many people will not have a very good time trying to get the keyboard keys to work on a website.